# I want to convert html to pdf. I have problem in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I have a HTML element that I want to convert to PDF. I don't want to convert it to an image and then to PDF, but to PDF directly. But the Turkish characters are broken. My export function:

```
const ExportPDF = (FileName, Component, Size) => {
        Size = Size ?? [1100, 1200]

        var pdf = new jsPDF({
            orientation: '1',
            unit: 'px',
            format: Size,
        })

        var options = {
            callback: (pdf) => {
                pdf.save((FileName ?? "output") + ".pdf");
            },
            x: 10,
            y: 10,
        }

        pdf.html(Component, options)
    }
```

I am using it like this:

```
<Button
    fullWidth
    variant="outlined"
    color="info"
    size="large"
    startIcon={<FilePdfBox />}
    onClick={() => {
        const PDFComponent = document.getElementById("pdf-content")
        ExportPDF("output-test", PDFComponent)
    }}
>
    Download as PDF
</Button>
```

How can I convert it to pdf without garbled characters?

I tried these methods:

```
        var options =  {
            encoding: 'UTF-8',
            ...
        }
```

```
pdf.addFont("../../font/arialuni.ttf", "ArialUnicodeMS", "normal")
pdf.setFont("ArialUnicodeMS")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a font that supports Turkish characters. Here's how you can add an font to support special Turkish characters in jsPDF

```
 const ExportPDF = (fileName, component, size) => {
   // Set default size to [1100, 1200] if size is not provided
   size = size || [1100, 1200];
 
   // Load the custom font
   const fontUrl =
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ink/3.1.10/fonts/Roboto/roboto-light-webfont.ttf';
   const fontName = 'Roboto';
   const fontFile = `${fontName}.ttf`;
 
   const loadFont = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   if (window.sessionStorage.getItem(fontName)) {
       resolve();
       return;
     }
 
     const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', fontUrl, true);
     xhr.responseType = 'blob';
 
     xhr.onload = () => {
       if (xhr.status === 200) {
         const blob = new Blob([xhr.response], { type: 'application/octet-     stream' });
         const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
         const reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
         reader.onload = () => {
           const base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
           window.sessionStorage.setItem(fontName, base64);
           resolve();
         };
       } else {
         reject(xhr.statusText);
       }
     };
 
     xhr.onerror = () => {
       reject(xhr.statusText);
     };
 
     xhr.send();
   });
 
   loadFont.then(() => {
     // Create a new jsPDF instance
     const doc = new jsPDF({
       orientation: 'portrait',
       unit: 'px',
       format: size,
     });
 
     // Embed the custom font in the PDF
     const fontBase64 = window.sessionStorage.getItem(fontName);
     doc.addFileToVFS(fontFile, fontBase64);
     doc.addFont(fontFile, fontName, 'normal');
 
     // Set the font for the PDF
     doc.setFont(fontName);
 
     // Get the HTML element you want to convert to a PDF
     const element = component;
 
     // Add the HTML element to the PDF
     const options = {
       callback: (pdf) => {
         pdf.save(`${fileName || 'output'}.pdf`);
       },
       x: 10,
       y: 10,
     };
     doc.html(element, options);
   });
 };
```